# Determine compatible Versions of Spring Modules and other libraries

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Which is the best way to determine the versions for my Spring modules and other libraries in a Spring Boot project?

1. Versions for Spring Modules
2. Versions for Third Party libraries

There are a lot of question when you search for *"Compatible versions in Spring"*.
But all these questions are regarding specific libraries.

I would like to have general rules of how to determine compatible versions for my project.

Answer (score 2):

You may checkout my post on this [A comprehensive list of dependencies managed by latest Spring-Boot 2.3.2.RELEASE (as a custom parent)](https://medium.com/@ashutosh049/a-comprehensive-list-of-dependencies-managed-by-latest-spring-boot-2-3-2-release-8aa088674591)

That's is just a reference for how it should be, but you may discard the version in  as they will be managed indirectly by spring itself.

Ok so, this is something almost every spring developer stumble upon. Let me try to explain this how was I able to resolve all the managed and third party libraries.

Let's suppose you want to build spring-boot microservices with a centralized configuration server.
So we can take it as following modules:

1. A company project starter: acts as a parent, managing the dependency
2. A config-server
3. A config-client

and let's suppose you chose spring-boot `2.3.2` version, which I used and find more stable. You would expect all the managed ones are using this spring-boot `2.3.2` version directly or indirectly.

I would highly recommend using https://mvnrepository.com

artifact: `my_company-boot-starter-parent`

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

 <groupId>com.my_company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_company-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>my_company starter-parent</name>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

 <!-- ... -->
 <!-- ... -->
 <!-- other dependencies -->
 <!-- ... -->
 <!-- ... -->

</dependencyManagement>
```

If you got to [Spring Boot Starter Parent » 2.3.2.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.2.RELEASE), under Managed Dependencies you can see the comprehensive list of all the dependencies with default version that would be referenced implicitly with boot version `2.3.2`, see column `Version`.

The `Updates` column indicate that these managed dependencies are having their newest updates as this, but you are not required to override the dependency version of managed ones. If you intent to use more recent version, you have to chose more recent version of `spring-boot-starter-parent`. So let the spring download all the managed one itself.

With spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.2 , they do not mention which spring-cloud-dependencies verion you should use, and this is where we get stuck and we need to figure it out.

Let us got to [spring-cloud-dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies) . Hee you can see numerous version but which one to chose, it's like verifying which latest version uses spring-boot 2.3.2 indirectly.

You need to follow the managed dependency and go along with it until you find your parent version.

For example If you go for :

#### [Hoxton.SR6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Hoxton.SR6)

[Spring Cloud Dependencies(Hoxton.SR6)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Hoxton.SR6) -> [Spring Cloud Config Dependencies( 2.2.3.RELEASE)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-config-dependencies/2.2.3.RELEASE) -> [Spring Cloud Starter Config(2.2.3.RELEASE)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-config/2.2.3.RELEASE) -> [Spring Cloud Starter(2.2.3.RELEASE)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter/2.2.3.RELEASE) -> [Spring Boot Starter(2.3.0.RELEASE)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.3.0.RELEASE)

Here you can see, we end up using `Spring Boot Starter(2.3.0.RELEASE)` which is not what we expected it to be.

#### [Hoxton.SR7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Hoxton.SR7)

[Spring Cloud Dependencies(Hoxton.SR7)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Hoxton.SR7) -> [Spring Cloud Config Dependencies(2.2.4.RELEASE)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-config-dependencies/2.2.4.RELEASE) -> [Spring Cloud Starter Config(2.2.4.RELEASE)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-config/2.2.4.RELEASE) -> [Spring Cloud Starter(2.2.4.RELEASE)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter/2.2.4.RELEASE) -> [Spring Boot Starter(2.3.2.RELEASE)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.3.2.RELEASE)

Here we end up using same boot version `2.3.2`. So in your parent `pom.xml`, you can set the spring cloud version as :

```xml
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

And in child poms (jars), you can just use the dependencies justby mentioning the `group` and `artifact`, skipping the version.

sample:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my_company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_company-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.googlejavaformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-java-format</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

See, we have not provided the any version here, so `spring-cloud-config-server` version would be auto managed and it would be `2.2.4.RELEASE` which again uses `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter` both of 2.3.2 version.

#### Third party libraries

This is somewhat based on language version. You might want to use the latest third-party libs which is most recent till your language version supports it.

Like lombok: `1.18.20`

Hope this might have helped you and others and provides an approach towards version compatibility.

> Tips: Never forget to check the Managed Dependency Coordinates in Aappendix of all the spring boot release page as they keep their managed dependencies & version there. Like this one [Appendix F: Dependency versions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dependency-versions)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Spring docs chart:

> `https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/`YOUR_VERSION`/reference/html/dependency-versions.html`

For e.g., if your Spring version is `2.7.2`, the link is:

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.2/reference/html/dependency-versions.html

you can navigate all the versions visiting:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/

Then just add the `/reference/html/dependency-versions.html` at the end

Answer (score 0):

**1. Use Spring Initializr**

Select all Spring modules you need in *spring initializr* and generate your code: https://start.spring.io/

You do not need to use the full generated code. But you should copy the library versions out of the generated pom.xml.

**2. Watch out for dependency pom.xml**

If available, import dependency pom.xml in your `dependencyManagement`.
Use the versions provided by these dependency poms.

E.g.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**Spring Dependency Version Documentation**

You can also check the [Spring Dependency Version Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#dependency-versions). But I prefer the initilizr, because it's easier to handle.